# Input type date is not working with some values angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a date input of html5,where I am using date picker,but my value contains some extra characters like "2019-01-01T23-00-11" which is not appearing first time with text box,Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <input  type="date" [(ngModel)]="name" value="name">
  <p>Value: {{ name }}</p>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name: string = '2019-01-01T23-00-11';
  //name: string = '2019-01-01';
  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: I would recommend using a date/datetime picker control, not the built in one in the browser because the browsers vary in their implementation (or lack there of).

Comment: The date string format doesnt seem to be correct

Comment: any simple method or control which can I use here?

Comment: For starters fix the value in the string, it is not formatted according to [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) standard so both the browser and any controls you might try to use would have a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the date input to datetime-local, and then change your string to have colon separated time instead of hyphen separated time, you will work. This will work in Chrome. Haven't tested all other browsers.

```
// In the html
<input  type="datetime-local" [(ngModel)]="name" value="name">

// In app.component.ts
name = `2019-01-01T23:00:11`
```

If you do this, the date and time will appear in the browser.

Comment: That depends on the browser and the version of that browser: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_datetime-local.asp

Comment: Updated answer to point out that this works in Chrome and not sure about other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the value before you get it

```
getDate(){

   let d = new Date(this.name)

     return `${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()}-${d.getDate()}`

   }
```

HTML

```
<input  type="date" [(ngModel)]="getDate()" value="name">
```